# $compile inside link function in angularjs directive not work as expected

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, angularjs-directive, compilation

I try do something with directive in angular, but I've some problem with $compile function in programmatically html element, call here "phe".

```
    var phe = angular.element('<div style="background-color:orange">{{value}}</div>');
```

When I append "phe" after or before the directive's element, it work like a charm...

```
    var $phe = $compile(phe)(scope);    
    element.after($phe);
```

but if I wrapped the directive element with this "phe" the $compile not work.

```
    element.wrap($phe);
```

Somebody have some idea?

I have made a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/0x2MmQ7WYmiNog0IEzTj?p=preview

Comment: what is $wrapper, how is it defined

Comment: hi entre, look my plunker, thanks! I correct :)

Answer (score 0):

it works if you change the compilation sequence... compile the element before placing it in the dom

```
        var phe_b = angular.element('<div style="background-color:orange"> b {{value}}</div>');
        var $phe_b = $compile(phe_b)(scope);
        element.before($phe_b);
```

do same for after...

Comment: Sorry, but if you see in the plunker, i did this... I don't understand, the problem is the wrap, now i change the plunker.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work with `wrap` is because `wrap` clones the DOM element. In other words, if you did:

```
var wrapper = angular.element("<div>");
element.wrap(wrapper);

console.log(wrapper[0] !== element[0].parentNode); // this would output "true"
```

So, the element that you compiled/linked is not the same that ends up in the DOM.

You could, of course, get the wrapping element (it's the return value of `wrap`) and `$compile` it, but you need to be careful not to re-compile/re-link certain directives that were applied on the current `element` (including the very same directive) and its children.

Comment: Thanks "New Dev", I understand, you and "entrem" gives to me a step to understand the angularjs way ! :) If you want look here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11887#issuecomment-102675864 there is something about that conferm that you suggest. Thanks again!

Comment: @zaquas, I'm not sure if you are asking something or confirming... The link you gave states the same thing I did, that `wrap` clones the DOM element, and so you end up with an uncompiled/unlinked element actually doing the wrapping. This, I believe, addresses your question of what is happening